# Get term name without a foreach loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, single, php

I currently have this:

```
  <?php
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'artist-genre');
  foreach($terms as $term) : ?>
  <li>
    <?php echo $term->name; ?>

  </li>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Just to list out the name on a custom post type page called `artwork`.

It's working, but I feel that doing a `foreach` loop for one thing is a little overkill.

Is there any other way to do this differently without the use of a `foreach` or is that the best way?

Comment: As suggested, use `get_the_terms`, which will pull the terms from cache (when the post was first queried). Worrying about a `foreach` loop is trivial when you're using `wp_get_post_terms`, which is a database hit everytime.

Answer (score 2):

What about [using](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list):

```
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'artist-genre', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' );
```

instead, to generate the HTML list?

Or [simply](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms):

```
the_terms( $post->ID, 'artist-genre', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' );
```

that's a wrapper for `get_the_term_list()`.

Also notice that you're missing the `is_wp_error()` check, in your code snippet, because `wp_get_post_terms()` can return the `WP_Error` object, for an unknown taxonomy. But the `the_terms` function takes care of that and returns `false` in that case.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll mess with that some more. I think more than anything I like to control some elements with CSS and custom class names, but this does help. I think it's just goofy to me cause I'm querying two different taxonomies with the same post type and this is all still new to me.

Comment: sure, play around and test and also try out the suggestions by Pieter. But please add all the relevant information into the question itself, to increase the change of getting as accurate answers as possible, thanks. @ultraloveninja

Answer (score 1):

If you are just after the term name in your code, you can add

```
array( 'fields' => 'names' )
```

Or for PHP 5.4+

```
['fields' => 'names']
```

as the third parameter to [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms). This will just retrieve the names of the terms attached to the post. You can then get and display the first post term name with

```
echo $terms[0]];
```

As @birgire already mentioned, you will need to check if `$terms` does not return a error and that there are actually values returned. Failing to do this will lead to a bug when `$terms` return an error of return an empty list